# iOS - Get current Wifi credentials (SSID & password)

Tags: ios, ios10

I recently bought a smart personal scales including an iOS-App.
While doing the wifi-setup of the scales on my iPhone, iOS asked me to allow this App to hand on my credentials of my current Wifi-network, I was logged in. I was looking for this feature quite intensive but without success, because I'd also like to just hand it on to another device to connect it to Wifi.

How can I do this in my App to fetch the Wifi credentials?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser

Comment: Ah thanks, sounds like I must have a MFI-certified device...

Comment: yeah, I didn't have enought time to explain earlier, but I've added a bit of additonal info below. But looks like it's not something you can use directly, it's provided in the underlying frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this functionality is built into the HomeKit / MFI frameworks and it not a usable API.

See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser)

So you can use the API to look for devices that aren't currently configured and configure them on your device. The underlying frameworks may share additional information but you wouldn't be able to request this information from another application as there isn't any public methods for it and it would definately be a security risk anyway.